# Freeing up space in my SVN repository

Tags: svn, repository, delete-file, obliterate

I have an SVN repository hosted on a freemium site with a maximum repository size. As I approach this capacity I am aware of files I've checked in that I know I can remove permanently to free up disk space. How do I tell SVN that a file can not only be deleted, but it's history as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a way in subversion to tell not to version a particular file or at least forget about a file when deleted. As it defeats the purpose of version control system. you will be able to achieve this by some tweaks if you have a local repository. However without any admin access for the repository, its going to be impossible to do this.

If it helps, [rsvndump](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/) is a tool to take a dump of a remote repository. With this you will be able to get the repository dump to your local system. To remove the unwanted files you can use this command "cat xxx-svn-dump | svndumpfilter exclude $file > new-svn-dump". Although with this you can reduce the size of the repository, you will not be able to update the orginal repository with this content.

Answer (score 6):

Look at this:

http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal says:

> There are special cases where you
>   might want to destroy all evidence of
>   a file or commit. (Perhaps somebody
>   accidentally committed a confidential
>   document.) This isn't so easy, because
>   Subversion is deliberately designed to
>   never lose information. Revisions are
>   immutable trees which build upon one
>   another. Removing a revision from
>   history would cause a domino effect,
>   creating chaos in all subsequent
>   revisions and possibly invalidating
>   all working copies.

Possible solution in this SO answer:

[Delete file contents from SVN history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205296/delete-file-contents-from-svn-history/205329#205329)

Answer (score 3):

Also you can prune your history. Say you have 100 revisions, you can keep the latest history, say 50 revisions. This may also reduce the size of your subversion repository.

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/current/repo -r50:100 > newsvn.dump
# you can delete the old repo and then
svnadmin create /path/to/new/repo
svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo < newsvn.dump
```