# how to delete large binary files from svn history?

Tags: svn, version-control, google-code, svndump, svndumpfilter

since i am using google code to host my svn repo, so [Delete file contents from SVN history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205296/delete-file-contents-from-svn-history) cannot solve my problem, because i cannot run svndump and svndumpfilter command on google code.

```
[mirror@home ins_ssh]$ svnadmin dump https://xxx.googlecode.com/svn/
svnadmin: 'https://xxx.googlecode.com/svn' is an URL when it should be a path
```

so is that possible to delete large binary files from google code's svn history?

especially when some sensitive data is commited to svn repo.

Comment: [Here's a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236215/1214939) from dr jerry.